# Dynamic does not respect return type

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# `dynamic` keyword. In one of my projects I tried to play with it and encountered some unexpected behavior. I managed to reproduce the situation with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static DateTime? DateOnly(DateTime? time)
    {
        return time.HasValue ? (System.DateTime?)time.Value.Date : null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic now = System.DateTime.Now;
        var date = DateOnly(now);
        Console.WriteLine(date.Value); // error thrown here
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I get a `RuntimeBinderException` saying

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value'.

So the variable `date` is treated as `DateTime` instead of `DateTime?`.

It looks like `dynamic` somehow ignores the return type declaration.
Should I avoid using `var` with `dynamic`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you pass a `dynamic` variable to the `DateOnly` method, the return type also becomes dynamic. So in this case, your `var date` is actually `dynamic date`. It contains a boxed nullable `DateTime`, but boxing doesn't preserve the "nullable" part, so in fact it's just a boxed `DateTime`, which doesn't have a `Value` property. So you should just do `Console.WriteLine(date)` to print the value.

As you can see, nullable types and `dynamic` don't play very well together...

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues. One is that `date` is still dynamic because the right hand side is a dynamic expression. If you had declared `date` with the specific type `DateTime?` you would not see this. The other issue is that you are returning a nullable value type and conversion to dynamic is considered boxing. Nullable value types are never boxed as such. The underlying value type is unwrapped so `date` behaves more like a reference of type `object` that can either have a DateTime or can be null, not a reference to a `DateTime?`. The binder then tries to resolve the property `Value` against DateTime and fails. If you try `Console.WriteLine(date)`, however it will fail as ambiguous because that method has so many overloads. So you will have to do something like `Console.WriteLine((object)date)`, at which point you might as well declare `date` as `object` for this simple example.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque yea I meant the other left. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

look at your function parameter, you're asking for a nullable type. DateTime (System.DateTime.Now) is a value type and value types are not nullable by default.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Nullable<T> is a struct.